# find distinct values from a list in another table using each kdb

Tags: kdb

I have found distinct b_market_order_no where event=`OvernightOrder from tb table, using either method

```
b_mkt_lst: select `g#b_market_order_no from tb where event=`OvernightOrder
b_mkt_lst: select distinct b_market_order_no from tb where  event=`OvernightOrder
```

For all records that have a b_market_order_no in that list need to find the b_orig_date for that b_market_order_no in another table called tbp, I try these two methods:

```
select b_orig_date from tbp where b_market_order_no in b_mkt_lst
select b_orig_date from tbp each b_mkt_lst
```

First one gives me incompatible length the second does not recognize b_orig_date, but "select b_orig_date from tbp" does return results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making some assumptions about your data:

```
q)t:([]c1:`a`b`c;c2:1 2 3)

/your length error is because you're comparing a list (b_market_order_no col) to a table (b_mkt_lst)
/similar to
q)select from t1 where c2 in select distinct c2 from ([]c2:1 3)
'length                        

/instead, use exec to extract a list (thus comparing a list to a list)
q)select from t1 where c2 in exec distinct c2 from ([]c2:1 3)
c1 c2
-----
a  1
c  3

/or turn the column(s) into a table to compare table to table
/(this is more useful when there's more than one column to compare)
q)select from t1 where ([]c2) in select distinct c2 from ([]c2:1 3)
c1 c2
-----
a  1
c  3
```

Comment: That works, but when I want to try "For records that have a b_market_order_no not in that list" I get mis match type. "select b_orig_date,b_market_order_no from tbp where b_market_order_no not in  b_mkt_lst"

Comment: syntax is wrong, should be `not b_market_order_no in b_mkt_lst`

Comment: When doing look back just using b_market_order_no isn't enough
b_market_order_no will be unique per day, sym & mkt. Does this mean I have to add sym&mkt to this line some where "select b_orig_date where b_market_order_no in exec distinct (b_market_order_no) from tb where event=`OvernightOrder"

Comment: It's hard to tell without seeing your actual data but it sounds like you might benefit from my last approach, something like `select from t where ([]date;b_market_order_no;sym;mkt) in select distinct date,b_market_order_no,sym,mkt from t2 where ....` Change the columns/keys accordingly to suit your dataset. At some point it might become more sensible to do some sort of join but again it depends on how the data is