# how to obtain a column from a table based on columns from another table kdb

Tags: kdb

I have queried 3 columns from a table as follows:

```
lst: distinct select  b_market_order_no,instrumentID,mkt from tb  where event=`OvernightOrder
```

based on these I want to query another table and get a dates column from it

```
select dates from tbp where
```

I am not quite sure how to apply the where clause or join clause here so values from lst get the corresponding dates column from tbp. Both tb and tbp tables have the same columns, they are created for different days from the same schema.

Comment: Would it be possible to include some example inputs and expected outputs to help those providing answers?

Comment: @kevbuntu isn't this the same question that you've asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61479802/find-distinct-values-from-a-list-in-another-table-using-each-kdb ? There's no need for two questions on the same topic. For now don't delete anything, keep the two questions as is but in future you can edit your original question if you think the wording isn't right or the answers aren't sufficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your use case correctly then you can use a table in your `where` clause as follows:

```
q)show tab1:([]a:1 2 3;b:4 5 6)
a b
---
1 4
2 5
3 6
q)show tab2:([]date:.z.d+1 2 3;a:2 3 4;b:5 6 7)
date       a b
--------------
2020.04.29 2 5
2020.04.30 3 6
2020.05.01 4 7
q)select date from tab2 where([]a;b)in tab1
date
----------
2020.04.29
2020.04.30
```

Basically this builds up a table of the relevant columns from `tab2` that are in `tab1` and compares them.

If the schema of the table being joined is variable another approach may be required, such as this:

```
q)select date from tab2 where(cols[tab1]#tab2)in tab1
date
----------
2020.04.29
2020.04.30
```

Or even using `lj` and adding an additional Boolean column to mark valid rows in `tab1` to select from `tab2`:

```
select date from(tab2 lj cols[tab1]xkey update c:1b from tab1)where c
```

Comment: I think this works if I wanted to load this into the database would this work: (`PATH/table/column) set dates where ([]b_market_order_no;instrumentID;mkt) in lst

Comment: That syntax seems to be indexing into a list called `dates` rather than a table and then saving the result to disk, rather than loading data from somewhere. This is speculation but if you wish to save to disk then what you might be looking for is something like `` `:PATH/table/column set select dates from tbp where ([]b_market_order_no;instrumentID;mkt) in lst`` but this just creates a single column flat table on disk so I'm not sure how much use that would be. Without example inputs and outputs I'm just speculating at an answer.

Comment: I was hoping that when I get my dates and I want to save them on to the database the where clause would link them into the appropriate rows! But is that the case?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, are you looking to update specific rows on disk? If so then this is not the method to achieve that.

Comment: yes, I want to bring dates from previous day to today's dates where this condition is met:  "select dates from tbp where ([]b_market_order_no;instrumentID;mkt) in lst ". and lst is: " lst: distinct select  b_market_order_no,instrumentID,mkt from tb  where event=`OvernightOrder " . tbp is the previous day table, tb is today's table

Comment: Sounds to me like you need to need to remove the old data for those dates from the partition and then append the new data. Assuming the data is partitioned.

Comment: This is new data being populated for today's date from previous day dates based on the where conditions on a partitioned data.